# "What Seem" vs "What Seems" with plural

Tags: agreement

I have prayed what seem like the same prayers for so long.

OR

I have prayed what seems like the same prayers for so long.

Comment: Welcome to our site. Which do you think is the correct one, and why?

Comment: **They** ***seem*** *like good prayers.* **It** ***seems*** *like a good prayer.* With the plural **prayers** you want to use the singular **seem**.  Or maybe there's something else going on that is causing confusion with this particular sentence?

Comment: I wasn't sure whether seems needed to agree with the "what" that precedes it or the "prayers" that followed.